# How To Set Popup Image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

```js
<div className="Image popup">
  <Modal
    isOpen={modalIsOpen}
    onRequestClose={closeModal}
    contentLabel="Image popup"
  >
    <img src="../img/navratri-1.png" alt="Image popup" />
    <button onClick={closeModal}>Close</button>
  </Modal>
</div>;

useEffect(() => {
  const hasShownImagePopup = localStorage.getItem("hasShownImagePopup");
  if (!hasShownImagePopup) {
    localStorage.setItem("hasShownImagePopup", "true");
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  }
}, []);

const closeModal = () => {
  setModalIsOpen(false);
};
```

In this, I am expecting a popup image to show on screen. Like a website where, when the user enters the home page, the image is shown, and when the user clicks the close button, the image is closed.

Answer (score 2):

```js
if (!hasShownImagePopup) {
```

Here, `!hasShownImagePopup` only returns `true` when `hasShownImagePopup` is "".

Because in Local Storage, data is stored in a string format.

So, we should check if `hasShownImagePopup` is not `"true"`.

```js
if (hasShownImagePopup !== "true") {
```

Also, you should probably set `hasShownImagePopup` in LocalStorage to `"false"` when you close the Modal. This will make the popup showup again when you visit the page again.

```js
const closeModal = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("hasShownImagePopup", "false");
  setModalIsOpen(false);
};
```

Here is a [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/etcfoobm-the-scripter/pen/gOZZJOX).